# Currying a function that takes infinite arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Using ES5, how do you curry a function that takes infinite arguments.

```js
function add(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
```

The function above takes only three arguments but we want our curried version to be able to take infinite arguments.

Hence, of all the following test cases should pass:

```js
var test = add(1);

test(2);     //should return 3
test(2,3);   //should return 6
test(4,5,6); //should return 16
```

Here is the solution that I came up with:

```js
function add(a, b, c) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    return function () {
        var secondArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var totalArguments = secondArgs.concat(args);

        var sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < totalArguments.length; i++) {
            sum += totalArguments[0];
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

However, I have been told that it's not very “functional” in style.

Comment: You might be missing a `+` in the first code chunk: by `return a + b c;` do you mean `return a + b + c;`?

Comment: @unpollo ..typo has been fixed

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Better move to `haskell` though.

Comment: test(2); it returned 4 when using your code。

sum += totalArguments[0]; 0 should be `i`

Comment: for checking complete infinite currying concept you can check this link https://thecodingcloud.com/infinite-currying-in-javascript/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the reason your `add` function is not very "functional" is because it is attempting to do more than just add up numbers passed to it. It would be confusing for other developers to look at your code, see an `add` function, and when they call it, get a function returned to them instead of the sum.

For example:

```
//Using your add function, I'm expecting 6
add(1,2,3) //Returns another function = confusing!
```

---

## The functional approach

The functional approach would be to create a function that allows you to curry any other functions, and **simplify your `add function`**:

```
function curry(fn) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    return function () {
        return fn.apply(this, args.concat(
                Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
        ));
    }
}

function add() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    return args.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    });
}
```

Now, if you want to curry this function, you would just do:

```
var curry1 = curry(add, 1);
console.log(
        curry1(2), // Logs 3
        curry1(2, 3), // Logs 6
        curry1(4, 5, 6) // Logs 16
);

//You can do this with as many arguments as you want
var curry15 = curry(add, 1,2,3,4,5);
console.log(curry15(6,7,8,9)); // Logs 45
```

If I still want to add `1, 2, 3` up I can just do:

```
add(1,2,3) //Returns 6, AWESOME!
```

## Continuing the functional approach

This code is now becoming reusable from everywhere.

You can use that curry function to make other curried function references without any additional hassle.

Sticking with the math theme, lets say we had a multiply function that multiplied all numbers passed to it:

```
function multiply() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    return args.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue * currentValue;
    });
}

multiply(2,4,8) // Returns 64

var curryMultiply2 = curry(multiply, 2);
curryMultiply2(4,8) // Returns 64
```

This functional currying approach allows you take that approach to any function, not just mathematical ones. Although the supplied `curry` function does not support all edge cases, it offers a functional, simple solution to your problem that can easily be built upon.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to the above problem. Sum of nth level curry by recursion

Trick: To stop the recursion I'm passing last () as blank**

```js
function sum(num1) {
        return (num2) => {
            if(!num2) {
                return num1;
            }
            return sum(num1 + num2);
        }
    }
console.log('Sum :', sum(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)())
```

Answer (score 7):

## Method 1: Using `partial`

A simple solution would be to use `partial` as follows:

```js
Function.prototype.partial = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.concat.apply([null], arguments);
    return Function.prototype.bind.apply(this, args);
};

var test = add.partial(1);

alert(test(2));     // 3
alert(test(2,3));   // 6
alert(test(4,5,6)); // 16

function add() {
    var sum = 0;
    var length = arguments.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        sum += arguments[i];
    return sum;
}
```

## Method 2: Single Level Currying

If you only want one level of currying then this is what I would do:

```js
var test = add(1);

alert(test(2));     // 3
alert(test(2,3));   // 6
alert(test(4,5,6)); // 16

function add() {
    var runningTotal = 0;
    var length = arguments.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        runningTotal += arguments[i];

    return function () {
        var sum = runningTotal;
        var length = arguments.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            sum += arguments[i];
        return sum;
    };
}
```

## Method 3: Infinite Level Currying

Now, here's a more general solution with infinite levels of currying:

```js
var add = running(0);

var test = add(1);

alert(+test(2));     // 3
alert(+test(2,3));   // 6
alert(+test(4,5,6)); // 16

function running(total) {
    var summation = function () {
        var sum = total;
        var length = arguments.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            sum += arguments[i];
        return running(sum);
    }

    summation.valueOf = function () {
        return total;
    };

    return summation;
}
```

A [running total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total) is the intermediate result of a [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). The `running` function returns another function which can be treated as a number (e.g. you can do `2 * running(21)`). However, because it's also a function you can apply it (e.g. you can do `running(21)(21)`). It works because JavaScript uses the `valueOf` method to automatically coerce objects into primitives.

Furthermore, the function produced by `running` is recursively curried allowing you to apply it as many times to as many arguments as you wish.

```js
var resultA = running(0);
var resultB = resultA(1,2);
var resultC = resultB(3,4,5);
var resultD = resultC(6,7,8,9);

alert(resultD + resultD(10)); // 100

function running(total) {
    var summation = function () {
        var sum = total;
        var length = arguments.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            sum += arguments[i];
        return running(sum);
    }

    summation.valueOf = function () {
        return total;
    };

    return summation;
}
```

The only thing you need to be aware of is that sometimes you need to manually coerce the result of `running` into a number by either applying the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to it or calling its `valueOf` method directly.

Comment: the requirement is not to pass an array input. Also i am not looking for someone to re-define the problem.. but more of what an suitable solution would be.. thanks for trying though..

Comment: @SMV I updated my answer. Is that a suitable solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is more generic approach by defining a curry function that takes minimum number of arguments when it evaluates the inner function. Let me use ES6 first (ES5 later), since it makes it more transparent:

```
var curry = (n, f, ...a) => a.length >= n
    ? f(...a)
    : (...ia) => curry(n, f, ...[...a, ...ia]);
```

Then define a function that sums all arguments:

```
var sum = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

then we can curry it, telling that it should wait until at least 2 arguments:

```
var add = curry(2, sum);
```

Then it all fits into place:

```
add(1, 2, 3) // returns 6
var add1 = add(1);
add1(2) // returns 3
add1(2,3) // returns 6
add1(4,5,6) // returns 16
```

You can even skip creating `add` by providing the first argument(s):

```
var add1 = curry(2, sum, 1);
```

ES5 version of curry is not as pretty for the lack of `...` operator:

```
function curry(n, f) {
    var a = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return a.length >= n
        ? f.apply(null, a)
        : function () {
            var ia = [].slice.call(arguments);
            return curry.apply(null, [n, f].concat(a).concat(ia));
        };
}

function sum() {
    return [].slice.call(arguments).reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
};
```

The rest is the same...

Note: If efficiency is a concern, you may not want to use `slice` on `arguments`, but copy it to a new array explicitly.

Comment: `curry(n, f, ...[...a, ...ia])` is equivalent to `curry (n, f, ...a, ...ia)`

Answer (score 0):

Bit late in this game, but here is my two cents. Basically this exploits the fact that functions are also objects in JavaScript.

```
function add(x) {
  if (x === undefined) {
    return add.numbers.reduce((acc, elem) => acc + elem, 0);
  } else {
    if (add.numbers) {
      add.numbers.push(x);
    } else {
      add.numbers = [x];
    }
  }
  return add;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Infinite sum with currying, you can pass a single parameter or multiple up-to infinite:

```
function adding(...arg) {

    return function clousureReturn(...arg1) {
        if (!arguments.length) {
            let finalArr = [...arg, ...arg1];
            let total = finalArr.reduce((sum, ele) => sum + ele);
            return total;
        }

        return adding(...arg, ...arg1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for **single level currying**

```
function sum() {
  let args = [...arguments];
  let total = args.reduce((total,num) => total + num,0);
  return total;
}
console.log(sum(1,2,3,4)) // 10
```

and the solution for **infinite level currying**

```
let sum= function (...args1) {
   let total =args1.reduce((total,num) => total + num,0)
   return function(...args2) {
     if(args2.length!== 0) {
       let total2 = args2.reduce((total,num)=>total + num,0);
       return sum(total,total2);
   }
   return total;
 };
};
console.log(sum(2,3,4)(2,3)(1)()); // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```js
const add = (one) => { // one: Parameter passed in test
  return (...args) => {
   // args: Array with all the parameters passed in test
    return one + args.reduce((sum, i) => sum + i, 0) // using reduce for doing sum
  }
}
var test = add(1);

console.log(test(2)); //should return 3
console.log(test(2, 3)); //should return 6
console.log(test(4, 5, 6)); //should return 16
```