# Create a function with an undetermined number of successive calls

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

As part of a programming challenge, we are tasked with creating a function with an undetermined number of successive calls. As an example, let's say the function returns simply the sum of the provided arguments, it should work as follows :

```
sum(4)() // 4
sum(4)(5)() // 9
sum(4)(5)(9)() // 18
sum(4)(5)(9)(1)() // 19
// etc...
```

The problem is simplified by the allowed empty function call at the end as an indication of end of calls.

I have worked on a solution that does the job but using global variables inside the function itself :

```
var sum = function (a) {
    if (!sum.init) {
        sum.total = 0;
        sum.init = true;
    }
    if (!arguments.length) {
        sum.init = false;
        return sum.total;
    }
    sum.total += a;
    return sum;
};
```

This solution works but uses state, global variables and function object trickery which is not ideal. My question here is whether there is a way to solve the problem in a purely recursive way.

As a side note, I do not believe the problem can be solved if that last empty call *()* is not provided, but if I'm wrong please let me know.

**Update**

This issue has been answered in CodeReview : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153999/129579

A neet solution that does not rely on global scope and is purely functional.

Comment: This looks like it belongs at codereview

Comment: Might be worth including the link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you research currying?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will post it in codereview.

Comment: epascarello, I did and I don't see how function currying would fit in this problem, a clue maybe ?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/ It's almost exactly what your syntax suggests.

Comment: @evolutionxbox not really, the key difference here is that the number of calls is undetermined, could be 2, 3 or 5000 successive calls which traditional currying would not solve.

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039020/currying-a-function-that-takes-infinite-arguments) even though the syntax isn't quite what you've asked for.

Comment: Yes, it's a much easier issue if you have undetermined number of arguments, but the challenge here is having undetermined number of function calls.

Comment: did you post on codereview? can you link the new post?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153979/create-a-function-with-an-undetermined-number-of-successive-calls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18067040/1048572

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of **closures** to acheive what you want like this:

```js
function sum(value){
  // the closure variable that will be accessible for all the _sum calls (initialised to 0 for every sum call).
  var result = 0;
  
  // the function that will be returned (sum will only get called once to initialize the result to 0. It's _sum which will be returned as much as possible)
  function _sum(a){
    // if we passed a parameter, then add it to result and return a new _sum
    if(typeof a != "undefined"){
      result += a;
      return _sum;
    }
    // if we didn't return the result
    else
      return result;
  }
  // of course after initializing result we need to call _sum that handle the actual summing and return whatever it returns (if value is defined, it will return another `_sum` if not it will return the value of result which will be 0 at first) from now on sum will have nothing to do with the rest of the calls (()()()... )
  return _sum(value);
}

console.log("sum() = " + sum());
console.log("sum(7)() = " + sum(7)());
console.log("sum(5)(6)(7)() = " + sum(5)(6)(7)());

// will return 0 because we call sum again
console.log("sum() = " + sum());
```

**NOTE:** That `sum(1)(7)(3)());` will call, in this order:

1. `sum` with the parameter `1` which will initialize `result` to `0` and call
2. `_sum` with the same parameter `1` which will add it to `result` and return a new inctance of `_sum` which will be called so the following
3. `_sum` get called with the parameter `7`, add it and return a new `_sum` so the new
4. `_sum` get called with the parameter `3`, ... spawn another
5. `_sum` that will have no parameter, therefore `if(typeof a != "undefined")` will fail and this `_sum` will return `result` instead.

The actual `sum` is only called once at the begining to do the initialization. It's, as I said, `_sum` that get chained after that all the way to the end.

Comment: if(a) means that 0 will return the result and break the chain.

Comment: @Francis Didn't think of that. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could use an outer function `sum` for the initial call and a closure over the starting value `a` and an inner function `fn`, which is repeatingly returned and only exited if `arguments.length` is equal to zero.

If a value `b` is supplied, the variable `a` gets updated and the inner function `fn` gets returned.

```js
function sum(a) {
    return function fn(b) {
        if (!arguments.length) {
            return a;
        }
        a += b;
        return fn;
    };
}

console.log(sum(1)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)());
```

Edit for calling sum with no argument

```js
function sum(a) {
    return arguments.length ?
        function fn(b) {
            if (!arguments.length) {
                return a;
            }
            a += b;
            return fn;
        } :
        0;
}

console.log(sum());
console.log(sum(1)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)());
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)());
```

Comment: What if he call sum with no parameters like: `sum();`?

Comment: please see the second approach, it returns as yours, zero.