# how to make multiple closure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the general solution of `closure` see below example.

```
function sum(b){
      return function(a){
        return a+b;
      }
    }

console.log(sum(2)(3));
```

It works correctly gives output `5`.But if I have this sum(2)(3)(4)...(100) times. How can I solve this issue?

how to find the sum in javascript 
**sum(2)(3)(4)...(100)**
Thanks

Comment: why not using `sum(2,3,4...,100)` looping over  `arguments` ?

Comment: that is fine ... but i need like that `sum(1)(2)...`

Comment: you trying to build your own weel i see

Comment: I think that's not support in js syntax.

Comment: @Wils That does support...

Comment: This question **NOT A DUPLICATE** of the referred question. I think the duplicate flag is inappropriate...

Comment: @RomeoSierra `I think the duplicate flag is inappropriate.`  You really need to give a reason for that thinking..

Comment: @Keith If you argue that this is a duplicate question, you should provide a valid reference. But I don't see the reference you have given discuss anything about the approach that has taken in the accepted answer. That is why I said that this is not a duplicate of the referred question..

Comment: @RomeoSierra  I'm confused, could you explain again, why you think this is not a duplicate?.

Comment: @Keith Sorry for the lack of clarity. Now, I see there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039020/currying-a-function-that-takes-infinite-arguments) that has been referred to, that is claimed as same as this question. But I don't see this question and [the question you have referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039020/currying-a-function-that-takes-infinite-arguments) are same. Yes they both are questioning a similar aspect. But the approaches are entirely different isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
function sum(v) {
    var f = function(b) {
        f.result += b;
        return f;
    }
    f.toString = function() { return this.result; };
    f.result = v;
    return f;
}

console.log(sum(2)(3)(4).result);
console.log(sum(2)(3)(4) + 100);
```

Output:

```
9
109
```

Explain: we make a function object `f`, if we call `f(123)`, it adds the `123` to its interval value `f.result` and return itself for next call. The `f.toString` is used for type-casting.

Comment: could you explain how it works.

Comment: it works I checked it correct way

Comment: @Wils edited with explanation

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/maniart/25a7a0939d0958c422c7

```
function sum(fn) {

    var args = [], fn;

    function exec() {
        return args.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
            return fn && fn.call(null, prev, curr);
        });
    }

    function addArg(arg) {
        if(arg) {
            args.push(arg);
            return addArg;
        } else {
            return exec();
        }
    }

    if(arguments.length < 1) {
        return sum;
    } else {
        fn = arguments[0];
        return addArg;
    }

}


//Sample use case: 

function add(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}
sum(add)(2)(3)(5)(8)(22)(230)(100)(10)();
```

Comment: Answers should contain code.  Links are fine, as long as the linked code is also in the answer.  If that link one day doesn't work then this answer is worthless.

Comment: This is a very nice (but a little complex) answer. Should be up-voted